# Login validation refreshes page immediately after function

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am making a login page with validation as part of my school project. Please note: I am aware this is unsecured I just want to get the method correct first then I am going to add a hash function I want to compare the user's input in the form with my default username and password and output an error message if they do not match, or redirect to a different webpage if they both do match.
This is the code I have so far:

```
<form>
<label for "username"> Username: </label>
<br>
<input type = "text" id = username>
<br>
<label for "password"> Password: </label>
<br>
<input type = "password" id = password>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = validationFunction()>
<br>
<div id = "error"></div>
<script>
    var x = document.getElementById("submit");
    x.addEventListener("click", validationFunction());
    event.preventDefault()
    function validationFunction() {
        var inputUsername = document.getElementById(username);
        if (inputUsername == "admin") {
            
        } else if (inputUsername != "admin") {
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "incorrect username or password";
        }
        var inputPassword = document.getElementById(password);
        if (inputPassword == "password"){
            
        } else if (inputPassword != "password"){
            document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "incorrect username or password";
        }
    }
    event.target.submit();
    

</script>
</form>
```

The code works for a second but the page immediately refreshes after showing the output - I am unsure of how to rectify this so that it remains on screen for the user to read and then enter the correct username and password combination.
I am also getting the error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
for the line:

```
x.addEventListener("click", validationFunction());
```

I thought I assigned the variable x to the submit button element, is there anything I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

When you submit a `form` the default behaviour you get is page refresh. In order to prevent it you need to use the `event` function preventDefault first thing when you submit it. `event.preventDefault()`.

```
<form onsubmit="onSubmitFunc(event)">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

function onSubmitFunc(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, do I put it in the HTML with the onclick in the submit button element or at the top of the script section?